# Mykrobe predictor AMR prediction not working

Tags: python, linux, sequence, bioinformatics

I am getting the following error message when trying to execute AMR prediction on the command line.

```
mykrobe predict tb_sample_id tb -1 /home/TB/demo_input_file_for_M.tuberculosis_app.fastq
```

The species chosen was Tuberculosis (TB), whereas the sample data file was pulled down from Mykrobe website (https://github.com/iqbal-lab/Mykrobe-predictor/releases/download/v0.1.1-beta/demo_input_file_for_M.tuberculosis_app.fastq.gz).

and the error message I'm getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mykrobe", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mykrobe==0.4.2', 'console_scripts', 'mykrobe')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykrobe/mykrobe_predictor.py", line 99, in main
    args.func(parser, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykrobe/mykrobe_predictor.py", line 32, in run_subtool
    run(parser, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykrobe/cmds/amr.py", line 127, in run
    cp.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykatlas/typing/typer/genotyper.py", line 73, in run
    self._run_cortex()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykatlas/typing/typer/genotyper.py", line 90, in _run_cortex
    self.mc_cortex_runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykatlas/cortex/mccortex.py", line 161, in run
    self._run_cortex()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykatlas/cortex/mccortex.py", line 173, in _run_cortex
    self._build_panel_binary_if_required()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mykatlas/cortex/mccortex.py", line 190, in _build_panel_binary_if_required
    subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of Mykrobe predictor. As someone above commented, probably the right place to ask this question is as a Github issue on our Mykrobe predictor repository:

https://github.com/iqbal-lab/Mykrobe-predictor/issues

Please feel free to raise the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `mccortex31` is missing.

Did you install it according to the [documentation](https://github.com/iqbal-lab/Mykrobe-predictor)?

```
cd Mykrobe-predictor
cd mccortex
make    
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/bin
cd ..
```

Comment: How to set the export path, use the following command:

`export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/bin`

Thank you, again.

Comment: Just open a Linux shell and paste the commands line by line. Alternatively you can use specify the path as follows:  `mykrobe predict --mccortex31_path /path/to/mmcortex/bin/mccortex31 tb_sample_id tb -1 demo_input_file_for_M.tuberculosis_app.fastq`

Comment: It seems to work when I used this instruction below.

`mykrobe predict --mccortex31_path ./mccortex31 -t 10 tb_sample_id tb -1 demo_input_file_for_M.tuberculosis_app.fastq`
However,  there are some warning in my nohup.out file.
`[seq_reader.c:277] Warn: Input file has min quality score 59 but qoffset is set to 33: demo_input_file_for_M.tuberculosis_app.fastq
  Have you predefined an incorrect fastq offset? Or is cortex guessing it wrong?`
btw, is it possible to export the JSON/tabular format file instead of in the nohup.out file?
Sorry to keep bothering you and thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a question which better suited for the authors of the software but feel free to open another question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you so much.